# What is a multithreading program and how does it work?

Tags: c#, multithreading, parallel-processing, language-agnostic

What is a multithreading program and how does it work exactly? I read some documents but I'm confused. I know that code is executed line by line, but I can't understand how the program manages this.
A simple answer would be appreciated.c# example please (only animation!)

Comment: If you think of program execution as a little elf running around inside your computer doing the tasks you've assigned, then picture two or three elves running around doing stuff at the same time. That is multi-threading. With Tasks and Threads, they're usually off doing things separate from one another. With Parallel, they're all working on one loop to see who can finish first. As a programmer, you need to make sure the elves all have something to do, and one doesn't show up for a lunch appointment only to find another off lollygagging around a WHILE loop. They get mad when that happens.

Comment: @arashzgh See [Using Web Workers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Using_web_workers) _"Web Workers provide a simple means for web content to run scripts in background threads. The worker thread can perform tasks without interfering with the user interface."_ What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Stackoverflow Documentation has a topic on this (threading) with a lot of examples: http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/c%23/51/threading

Comment: i need picture and animation

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> What is a multi-threading program and how does it work exactly?

Interesting part about this question is complete books are written on the topic, but still it is elusive to lot of people. I will try to explain in the order detailed underneath.

Please note this is just to provide a gist, an answer like this can never do justice to the depth and detail required. Regarding videos, best that I have come across are part of paid subscriptions (Wintellect and Pluralsight), check out if you can listen to them on trial basis, assuming you don't already have the subscription:

1. [Wintellect by Jeffery Ritcher](https://www.wintellectnow.com/Videos/Watch?videoId=thread-fundamentals) (from his Book, CLR via C#, has same chapter on Thread Fundamentals)
2. [CLR Threading by Mike Woodring](https://app.pluralsight.com/library/courses/clr-threading/table-of-contents)

**Explanation Order**

- What is a thread ?
- Why were threads introduced, main purpose ?
- Pitfalls and how to avoid them, using Synchronization constructs ?
- Thread Vs ThreadPool ?
- Evolution of Multi threaded programming API, like Parallel API, Task API
- Concurrent Collections, usage ?
- Async-Await, thread but no thread, why they are best for IO

> What is a thread ?

It is software implementation, which is purely a Windows OS concept `(multi-threaded architecture)`, it is bare minimum unit of work. Every process on windows OS has at least one thread, every method call is done on the thread. Each process can have multiple threads, to do multiple things in parallel (provided hardware support). 
Other `Unix` based OS are multi process architecture, in fact in Windows, even the most complex piece of software like `Oracle.exe` have single process with multiple threads for different critical background operations.

> Why were threads introduced, main purpose ?

Contrary to the perception that concurrency is the main purpose, it was robustness that lead to the introduction of threads, imagine every process on Windows is running using same thread (in the initial 16 bit version) and out of them one process crash, that simply means system restart to recover in most of the cases. Usage of threads for concurrent operations, as multiple of them can be invoked in each process, came in picture down the line. In fact it is even important to utilize the processor with multiple cores to its full ability.

> Pitfalls and how to avoid using Synchronization constructs ?

More threads means, more work completed concurrently, but issue comes, when same memory is accessed, especially for `Write`, as that's when it can lead to:

1. Memory corruption
2. Race condition

Also, another issue is thread is a very costly resource, each thread has a thread environment block, Kernel memory allocation. Also for scheduling each thread on a processor core, time is spent for context switching. It is quite possible that misuse can cause huge performance penalty, instead of improvement.
To avoid Thread related corruption issues, its important to use the Synchronization constructs, like `lock, mutex, semaphore,` based on requirement. Read is always thread safe, but Write needs appropriate Synchronization.

> Thread Vs ThreadPool ?

Real threads are not the ones, we use in C#.Net, that's just the managed wrapper to invoke Win32 threads. Challenge remain in user's ability to grossly misuse, like invoking lot more than required number of threads, assigning the processor affinity, so isn't it better that we request a standard pool to queue the work item and its windows which decide when the new thread is required, when an already existing thread can schedule the work item. Thread is a costly resource, which needs to be optimized in usage, else it can be bane not boon.

> Evolution of Multi threaded programming, like Parallel API, Task API

From .Net 4.0 onward, variety of new APIs Parallel.For, Parallel.ForEach for data paralellization and Task Parallelization, have made it very simple to introduce concurrency in the system. These APIs again work using a Thread pool internally. Task is more like scheduling a work for sometime in the future. Now introducing concurrency is like a breeze, though still synchronization constructs are required to avoid memory corruption, race condition or thread safe collections can be used.

> Concurrent Collections, usage ?

Implementations like `ConcurrentBag, ConcurrentQueue, ConcurrentDictionary`, part of `System.Collections.Concurrent` are inherent thread safe, using `spin-wait` and much easier and quicker than explicit `Synchronization`. Also much easier to manage and work. There's another set API like `ImmutableList` `System.Collections.Immutable`, available via [nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Collections.Immutable/), which are thread safe by virtue of creating another copy of data structure internally.

> Async-Await, thread but no thread, why they are best for IO

This is an important aspect of concurrency meant for `IO` calls (disk, network), other APIs discussed till now, are meant for compute based concurrency so threads are important and make it faster, but for IO calls thread has no use except waiting for the call to return, IO calls are processed on hardware based queue `IO Completion ports`

Comment: Welcome, please go through video links, they have lot of useful information

Answer (score 6):

A simple analogy might be found in the kitchen.

You've probably cooked using a recipe before -- start with the specified ingredients, follow the steps indicated in the recipe, and at the end you (hopefully) have a delicious dish ready to eat.  If you do that, then you have executed a *traditional (non-multithreaded) program*.

But what if you have to cook a full meal, which includes a number of different dishes?  The simple way to do it would be to start with the first recipe, do everything the recipe says, and when it's done, put the finished dish (and the first recipe) aside, then start on the second recipe, do everything it says, put the second dish (and second recipe) aside, and so on until you've gone through all of the recipes one after another.  That will work, but you might end up spending 10 hours in the kitchen, and of course by the time the last dish is ready to eat, the first dish might be cold and unappetizing.

So instead you'd probably do what most chefs do, which is to start working on several recipes at the same time.  For example, you might put the roast in the oven for 45 minutes, but instead of sitting in front of the oven waiting 45 minutes for the roast to cook, you'd spend the 45 minutes chopping the vegetables.  When the oven timer rings, you put down your vegetable knife, pull the cooked roast out of the oven and let it cool, then go back to chopping vegetables, and so on.  If you can do that, then you are successfully multitasking several recipes/programs.  That is, you aren't literally working on multiple recipes at once (you still have only two hands!), but you are jumping back and forth from following one recipe to following another whenever necessary, and thereby making progress on several tasks rather than twiddling your thumbs a lot.  Do this well and you can have the whole meal ready to eat in a much shorter amount of time, and everything will be hot and fresh at about the same time too.  If you do this, you are executing a simple *multithreaded program*.

Then if you wanted to get *really* fancy, you might hire a few other chefs to work in the kitchen at the same time as you, so that you can get even more food prepared in a given amount of time.  If you do this, your team is doing *multiprocessing*, with each chef taking one part of the total work and all of them working simultaneously.  Note that each chef may well be working on multiple recipes (i.e. multitasking) as described in the previous paragraph.

As for how a *computer* does this sort of thing (no more analogies about chefs), it usually implements it using a list of ready-to-run threads and a timer.  When the timer goes off (or when the thread that is currently executing has nothing to do for a while, because e.g. it is waiting to load data from a slow hard drive or something), the operating system does a *context switch*, in which pauses the current thread (by putting it into a list somewhere and no longer executing instructions from that thread's code anymore), then pulls another ready-to-run thread from the list of ready-to-run threads and starts executing instructions from that thread's code instead.  This repeats for as long as necessary, often with context switches happening every few milliseconds, giving the illusion that multiple programs are running "at the same time" even on a single-core CPU.  (On a multi-core CPU it does this same thing on each core, and in that case it's no longer just an illusion; multiple programs really *are* running at the same time)

Comment: `multithreading` paragraph reminds me more of `asynchronicity`. This thread just jumps from one task to the other, as you mentioned, and no other threads are actually created. So is it valid to call it `multithreading`?

Comment: The thread doesn't jump from one task to another; the thread is (by definition) a single sequence of related instructions.  It's the *CPU* (i.e. the chef in the analogy, not the recipe) that jumps from one task to another, i.e. executes some instructions from thread A, then some from B, then some from C, then some from A again.

Comment: @Gabrielius (you *could* write a single-threaded program that did the same thing, of course, but then you'd be essentially implementing your own primitive task-scheduler within that single thread)

Comment: Jeremy, yes, I understand. I incorrectly assumed that the *chef* is the *thread*, when it is actually the **recipe**. So it is **not** the thread that does something, but *CPU* which switches *threads* (*recipes*) and performs instructions from them. I am a bit ashamed after writing all those multi-threaded apps while not knowing the basics! Thanks, learned something new!

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you refer to Microsoft's very own documentation of the .net class System.Threading.Thread?

It has a handfull of simple example programs written in C# (at the bottom of the page) just as you asked for:

[Thread Examples](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Anything that's just a mere reference, please add as a comment instead of Answer, as there's not value add out here

Comment: this should be comment first . and can u see my question? my question ask animation .

Comment: @arashzgh: and tomorrow you will add to your question that you want only examples using WPF?

Comment: @Mrinal Kamboj: sorry just earned the privilege to comment, so I was forced to answer instead of comment.

Answer (score 0):

actually multi thread is do multiple process at the same time together . and you can complete process parallel .

Answer (score -1):

it's actually multi thread is do multiple process at the same time together . and you can complete process parallel . you can take task from your main thread then execute some other way and done .

Comment: please use comment part..!