# C# Threading - Using a class in a thread-safe way vs. implementing it as thread-safe

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, thread-safety

Suppose I want to use a non thread-safe class from the `.Net Framework` (the documentation states that it is not thread-safe). Sometimes I change the value of `Property X` from one thread, and sometimes from another thread, but I never access it from two threads at the same time. And sometimes I call `Method Y` from one thread, and sometimes from another thread, but never at the same time.

Is this means that I use the class in a thread-safe way, and the fact that the documentation state that it's not thread-safe
is no longer relevant to my situation?

If the answer is No: Can I do everything related to a specific object in the same thread - i.e, creating it and calling its members always in the same thread (but not the GUI thread)? If so, how do I do that? (If relevant, it's a WPF app).

Comment: Yes - if you can absolutely guarantee that the methods will never get hit by two threads at the same time - then it'll work. It's still not thread safe - it's just not being used in a true "multithreaded" environment (>1 thread at once). But you need to make sure it doesn't get hit twice @ once. Let me also state that this is in your case - if something gets changed by one thread when another is depending on its value (like say modifying a List) - even if the threads are apart when it happens - that's bad news.

Comment: Guys, this is a perfectly valid question, the asker has unclarities about thread safeness. Do not downvote a question just because it was asked by a beginner.

Comment: Bohoo, let me give you an analogous situation. Let us suppose there is a crocodile in your bathroom. Although, you can install some ropes on the ceiling and use those for movement, if that provides you a quasi safe state that still leaves your bathroom in an unsafe state.

Comment: You are right to have these doubts and unfortunately answer is yes/no. If with "safe" you mean that it won't crash then maybe. If you mean that it will work as intended...maybe no. The other thread MAY not even see changed properties. A hood answer about this should be pretty long

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Suppose I want to use a non thread-safe class from the .Net Framework (the documentation states that it is not thread-safe).

"Thread-safe" has a number of different meanings. Most objects fall into one of three categories:

- Thread-affine. These objects can only be accessed from a single thread, never from another thread. Most UI components fall into this category.
- Thread-safe. These objects can be accessed from any thread at any time. Most synchronization objects (including concurrent collections) fall into this category.
- One-at-a-time. These objects can be accessed from one thread at a time. This is the "default" category, with most .NET types falling into this category.

> Sometimes I change the value of Property X from one thread, and sometimes from another thread, but I never access it from two threads at the same time. And sometimes I call Method Y from one thread, and sometimes from another thread, but never at the same time.

As another answerer noted, you have to take into consideration instruction reordering and cached reads. In other words, it's not sufficient to just do these at *different* times; you'll need to implement proper barriers to ensure it is guaranteed to work correctly.

The easiest way to do this is to protect all access of the object with a `lock` statement. If all reads, writes, and method calls are all within the same lock, then this would work (assuming the object does have a one-at-a-time kind of threading model and not thread-affine).

Comment: Can you explain what do you mean by "If all reads, writes, and method calls are all within the same lock"?

Comment: @Bohoo: If they are all surrounded by a `lock` statement that locks on the same object.

Comment: I understand. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

No, it is not thread safe. As a general rule, you should never write multi threaded code without some kind of synchronization. In your first example, even if you somehow manage to ensure that modifying/reading is never done at the same time, still there is a problem of caching values and instructions reordering.

Just for example, CPU caches values into a register, you update it on one thread, read it from another. If the second one has it cached, it doesn't go to RAM to fetch it and doesn't see the updated value.

Take a look at this great post for more info and problems with writing lock free multi threaded code [link](http://blog.coverity.com/2014/03/12/can-skip-lock-reading-integer/#.V-Z3XPB96VM). It has a great explanation how CPU, compiler and CLI byte code compiler can reorder instructions.

Comment: Your point is mostly related to using a Synchronization construct even for read access and that's what Eric's article suggest, but doesn't answer the core questions posted by the OP

Answer (score 1):

> Suppose I want to use a non thread-safe class from the .Net Framework (the documentation states that it is not thread-safe). Sometimes I change the value of Property X from one thread, and sometimes from another thread, but I never access it from two threads at the same time. And sometimes I call Method Y from one thread, and sometimes from another thread, but never at the same time.

All `Classes` are by default non thread safe, except few `Collections` like `Concurrent Collections` designed specifically for the `thread safety`. So for any other class that you may choose and if you access it via `multiple threads` or in a `Non atomic` manner, whether `read / write` then it's imperative to introduce thread safety while changing the state of an object. This only applies to the objects whose state can be modified in a multi-threaded environment but Methods as such are just functional implementation, they are themselves not a state, which can be modified, they just introduce thread safety for maintaining the object state.

> Is this means that I use the class in a thread-safe way, and the fact that the documentation state that it's not thread-safe is no longer relevant to my situation? If the answer is No: Can I do everything related to a class in the same thread (but not the GUI thread)? If so, how do I do that? (If relevant, it's a WPF app).

For a Ui application, consider introducing `Async-Await` for IO based operations, like file read, database read and use `TPL` for compute bound operations. Benefit of `Async-Await` is that:

- It doesn't block the Ui thread at all, and keeps Ui completely responsive, in fact post `await` Ui controls can be directly updated with no Cross thread concern, since only one thread is involved
- The TPL concurrency too makes compute operations blocking, they summon the threads from the thread Pool and can't be used for the Ui update due to Cross thread concern

> And last: there are classes in which one method starts an operation, and another one ends it. For example, using the SpeechRecognitionEngine class you can start a speech recognition session with RecognizeAsync (this method was before the TPL library so it does not return a Task), and then cancel the recognition session with RecognizeAsyncCancel. What if I call RecognizeAsync from one thread and RecognizeAsyncCancel from another one? (It works, but is it "safe"? Will it fail on some conditions which I'm not aware of?)

As you have mentioned the `Async` method, this might be an older implementation, based on `APM`, which needs `AsyncCallBack` to coordinate, something on the lines of `BeginXX, EndXX`, if that's the case, then nothing much would be required to co-ordinate, as they use AsyncCallBack to execute a callback delegate. In fact as mentioned earlier, there's no extra thread involved here, whether its old version or new `Async-Await`. Regarding task cancellation, `CancellationTokenSource` can be used for the `Async-Await`, a separate cancellation task is not required. Between multiple threads coordination can be done via Auto / Manual ResetEvent.
If the calls mentioned above are synchronous, then use the Task wrapper to return the Task can call them via Async method as follows:

```
await Task.Run(() => RecognizeAsync())
```

Though its a sort of Anti-Pattern, but can be useful in making whole call chain `Async`

**Edits (to answer OP questions)**

> Thanks for your detailed answer, but I didn't understand some of it. At the first point you are saying that "it's imperative to introduce thread safety", but how?

1. Thread safety is introduced using synchronization constructs like `lock, mutex, semaphore, monitor, Interlocked,` all of them serve the purpose of saving an object from getting corrupt / race condition. I don't see any steps.

> Does the steps I have taken, as described in my post, are enough?

2. I don't see any thread safety steps in your post, please highlight which steps you are talking about

> At the second point I'm asking how to use an object in the same thread all the time (whenever I use it). Async-Await has nothing to do with this, AFAIK.

3. Async-Await is the only mechanism in concurrency, which since doesn't involved any extra thread beside calling thread, can ensure everything always runs on same thread, since it use the `IO completion ports` (hardware based concurrency), otherwise if you use `Task Parallel library`, then there's no way for you to ensure that same / given thread is always use, as that's  a very high level abstraction

Check one of my recent detailed answer on threading [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39602603/1559611), it may help in providing some more detailed aspects

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer, but I didn't understand some of it. At the first point you are saying that "it's imperative to introduce thread safety", but how? Does the steps I have taken, as described in my post, are enough? At the second point I'm asking how to use an object in the same thread all the time (whenever I use it). Async-Await has nothing to do with this, AFAIK.

Answer (score 0):

It is not thread-safe, as the technical risk exists, but your policy is designed to cope with the problem and work around the risk. So, if things stand as you described, then you are not having a thread-safe environment, however, you are safe. For now.

Comment: What happens with cached values? I don't see his model being safe in any way when it comes to one thread updating values and another thread reading stale ones.

Comment: @InBetween, this is not a safe model, but if the op knows about the pitfalls and avoids them, then there will be no problems whatsoever, although a safe model should be preferred, as described in the analogous example about the crocodile in the bathroom described below the question.